# How to avoid duplicate entries in Postgres database? Entries contain varying value

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, save

Method to store entity:

```
PoolDef poolDef = new PoolDef();
        poolDef.setDate_from(date);
        poolDef.setName(poolList.getPoolList().get(i).getName());

        poolDefRepository.save(poolDef);
```

Entity itself:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"Id"})
@Transactional
@Entity
public class PoolDef {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long Id;

private String name;

@Column(name = "date_from", columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone not null")
private OffsetDateTime date_from;
}
```

The only value that varies is the `date_from`. I do not know, why new entries are being added to the database and not just get updated. I have the `@EqualsAndHashcode` that are being built based on primary `Id` key, so the `date_from` should not matter. Every method invocation creates a new entry with a completely new `Id`...

Comment: You create new entity and save it to database. Why shouldn't it have new Id?

Comment: `save` method from `CRUD repository` is coded that way, that if the entity is new it will call `persist` on `EntityManager`. Otherwise it's `merge`. I have a custom `EqualsAndHashCode`, so it should be treated as the same, shouldn't it? I'm a beginner, so please prove me wrong.

Comment: You are right. And from your code your entity is new. `PoolDef poolDef = new PoolDef();` Your `EqualsAndHashCode` makes any instances with same Id equals.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is your

```
GenerationType.IDENTITY
```

the documentation says:

> Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for
>   the entity using a database identity column.

Now the key question is, what SQL is getting generated. Can you please trace the insert SQLs generated?

Also I would prefer to use SEQUENCES of databases. So I do not have to mess around with the Identities of the persistence provider and any application will behave the same against the database if you use the SEQUENCES of databases for your ID/primary key columns.

Also a issue could be your DDL for the table creation, but I assume you know how to define the database tables with the given constraints.